# DynDns Wildcard Subdomain in Apache

Tags: apache, subdomain, dyndns

I've got a dyndns domain (lets say example.dyndns.org). Currently I can access different wep applications by different ports

- example.dyndns.org:10001 gets WebApp1
- example.dyndns.org:10002 gets WebApp2
- example.dyndns.org gets my website

Now I activated wildcard subdomains in my dyndns profile and I want my apache to deliver

- WebApp1 on web1.example.dyndns.org and example.dyndns.org:10001
- WebApp2 on web2.example.dyndns.org and example.dyndns.org:10002
- Website on example.dyndns.org

So currently I have got the following setup:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
Listen 10001
Listen 10002

<VirtualHost *:10001>
    ServerName ...
    DocumentRoot ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:10002>
    ServerName ...
    DocumentRoot ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName ...
    DocumentRoot ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I want to add

```
<VirtualHost web1.example.dyndns.org:80>
    ServerName ...
    DocumentRoot ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

But this does not work. Any suggestions why?

Comment: I think it this question should moved to ServerFault page .

Comment: Sorry. How can I do this?

Comment: You are unable to do this. Only moderators have the power. What you can do is, visit that page, create a post there and delete this post.